# Pass ANSI string from Java to C++ (JNI)

Tags: java-native-interface

I have a file with an arabic content (encoded in ANSI). I wrote the C++ code responsible for processing this text.
**Now i want to pass this text from Java (without changing the encoding) to the C++ code and get the result back after processing.**

Answer (score 0):

Send the content as byte arrays.  No idea what you mean by 'ANSI', but if you don't want to change the encoding, just handle them as byte arrays.